BC1 code decoding for texels
I want to implement a BC1 decoder. A single BC1 compressed block consists of 64-bit, where bits are stored like this:
63       55       47       39       31       23       15       7        0
| c0-low | c0-hi  | c1-low | c1-hi  | codes0 | codes1 | codes2 | codes3 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

According to this page, codes are decoded as:
31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
 | c00 | c10 | c20 | c30 | c01 | c11 | c21 | c31 | c02 | c12 | c22 | c32 | c03 | c13 | c23 | c33 
 |       codes3          |       codes2          |       codes1          |       codes0
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

however in this page codes are decoded as:
c0_lo, c0_hi, c1_lo, c1_hi, bits_0, bits_1, bits_2, bits_3
bits   = bits_0 + 256 * (bits_1 + 256 * (bits_2 + 256 * bits_3))
code(x,y) = bits[2*(4*y+x)+1 .. 2*(4*y+x)+0]

I think they are not compatible. For example, the upper-left texel should be (x,y)=(0,3) (because OpenGL start point is at the lower-left), and according to the the first decoding scheme bits 7-6 should be used, however for the second decoding scheme bits 25-24 should be used. Am I interpreting it wrong?
NOTE: Is it due to different endianness? The problem might be the first decoding scheme is using little-endian but the second is using big-endian.
